# Tell to Microsoft Edge to forget an outlook account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-edge

I'm using two Microsoft Outlook accounts (A and B) in Microsoft Edge; the problem is that, when I open Edge, the default account is always A, also if I sign out. How can I tell to Edge to forget the account A so that, when I open it, I can see only the B account?

Comment: You can use a new private browsing window to log into the other account

Comment: Hello @Virsacer thank you for your suggestion. I prefer to avoid to open a new window every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to remove the other account on Outlook web mail?

If so, please follow the below steps:

1.Click your account in the upper right corner>Click to switch to the account you want to keep> Then Click the "..." on the right of the account you want to remove>click **Sign Out and forget**. Wait for a while until fully sign out.

[image]

2.Close all edge windows and open Outlook.com again> Click sign in>Click **Manage personal info** in the Sign in window.

[image]

3.Remove the account credential you don't need.

Hope the above help!